# Creating a multidimensional array from a string with delimiter

Tags: c#

I have an comma separated string like this:

```
string myString = "1,a,b,C1,,#2,d,e,C2,,#3,f,g,C3,,#4,h,i,C4,,#";
```

This is basically the data from an csv file where I am using reader to read from file.

In the above string  ',' represents the data delimeter while '#' represents EOL of the file.

```
myString = myString.TrimEnd('#'); //Removing extra # in the end.
//Result of above 1,a,b,C1,,#2,d,e,C2,,#3,f,g,C3,,#4,h,i,C4,,
```

I want to convert the above into multidimentional array, loop through it reading value of each row data and create my own json.

So I started with the below code. This would result me with row and column count.

```
int rowCount = result.TrimEnd('#').Split('#').Count();
int colCount = result.TrimEnd('#').Split('#')[0].TrimEnd(',').Split(',').Length;

//Defining my object which I want to fill.
JObject myObject = new JObject();
```

Below I want to loop through row and column getting data value from each row and column

```
for (int row = o ; row <= rowCount; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col <= colCount; col++)
    {
       //So here I want to do something like:
       var rowValue = multiArray[row][col];

       //After getting the row value below is the logic to add to my object
       if(col == 0)
       {
            myObject.Add("first", rowValue);    
       }
       else if(col == colCount)
       {
            myObject.Add("last", rowValue);
       }
       else
       {
            myObject.Add(col, rowValue);
       }
    }
}
```

So my question is how can I create the multidimentional array "multiArray" in my code.

Example of my json:

```
{
  "first": 1
  "1": a,
  "2": b,
  "last": C1
},
{
  "first": 2
  "1": c,
  "2": d,
  "last": C2
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included what you want your final JSON to look like given the starting string `"1,a,b,C1,,#2,d,e,C2,,#3,f,g,C3,,#4,h,i,C4,,#"`

Comment: So where are you stuck?

Comment: @MattBurland my final json would depend upon the rows and columns of the file ie the string. I would take care of creating the json its just that I dont know to create the multi array "multiArray" in my code above from which I can loop through. I have updated my post with json.

Comment: @OleEHDufour as mentioned in my post, I dont know how to create the "multiarray" so that I can loop through it.

Comment: @user1563677 - you have an example input, what's the example output for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code creates and fills your multi-dimensional array, but there is a problem with your data. Because of the extra commas your json will not look like your sample json.

```
string myString = "1,a,b,C1,,#2,d,e,C2,,#3,f,g,C3,,#4,h,i,C4,,#".TrimEnd('#');

var rows = myString.Split('#');
var rowCount = rows.Length;
var columnCount = rows[0].Split(',').Length;

string[,] multiArray = new string[rowCount, columnCount];

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i ++)
{
    var values = rows[i].Split(',');
    for (int j = 0; j < columnCount && j < values.Length; j++)
    {
        multiArray[i,j] = values[j];
    }
}
```

The results I get from this are that there is a 4x6 array with only 4 values in each row.

Comment: Thanks will check and get back

Comment: I had to adjust a little bit with my code but this works fine.